# Show a predicate is primitive recursive

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, recurrence-relation, primitive-recursion

Let $S(i,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be a primitive recursive predicate. 
 \begin{equation}
 f(i_1,i_2,x_1,\ldots, x_n) =
 \begin{cases}
  1 &\text{ when for all i, }\; i_1 \le i \le i_2,\; S(i,x_1, \ldots, x_n)=1\\
  0 &\text{ otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Show that $f(i_1,i_2,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is also primitive recursive

I use Davis Computability and Complexity book.
I get I need to write as described in this page. 
[Show $x^y$ is a primitive recursive function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/show-xy-is-a-primitive-recursive-function)

But how to do for predicates? Even a similar example which has predicates would be very helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: show that finite case distinction with primitive-recursive predicates is primitive recursive. Use this to complete your task.

Comment: The `cases` environment lets you use an `&` to separate the function value from the text describing the case.

Comment: Yeah I was asking how to approach such a problem. How to begin, because I have seen no examples similar to this. Not a full answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Could you clarify your comment? I have maybe proved a function by cases is primitive recursive. Are you suggesting what to do after that?

Comment: It's not about case distinction. It's about universal quantification over a fixed range.

Comment: Hint: $\forall i \leq n . S(i,x) = 1$ is calculated as $\prod_{i =0}^n S(i,x)$.

Comment: @DavidHamide I was commenting about your use of LaTeX. You had something like `\begin{cases} 1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{if...}`. Using `&` instead of that train of `\,`s gives the correct spacing. Also, `\quad` and `\qquad` are your friend if you do need to insert a long-ish manual space.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks that helps a lot. I was thinking like $\le$, $\forall i \leq n$, S,$\ge$, definition by cases were all primitive recursive , Hence f is primitive recursive.

Comment: Consider first the easier case $g(n,\ldots) = f(0,n,\ldots)$ and define that by (primitive) recursion on $n$. Then define $f$ in terms of $g$. Start by checking whether $i_1 > i_2$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Do not get confused by the word "predicate". It is actually quite common to show that a function is primitive recursive by using another function for which we already know that it is primitive recursive in its definition.

For example, in the proof that multiplication is primitive recursive one usually defines multiplication using addition, which is not a basic primitive recursive function.

If "predicate" confuses you check out its definition, e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)). It is just a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So you can use a primitive recursive predicate just as a primitive recursive function of that kind.

All you need to show is, as mentioned in the comments, that the bounded quantification is primitive recursive.